# spark intelij submit java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Servlet

Tags: maven, hadoop, servlets, apache-spark

When I use IntelIJ as IDE for spark applications, I can run the application in IDE while failed to run spark-submit after exporting this application with all the required dependencies.

Getting ERROR message as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Servlet
at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI.attachPage(WebUI.scala:80)

...

at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 27 more
```

But when I have check the jar, javax/servlet/Servlet is just there! why?
I use jars with hadoop, spark and hive instead of maven pom. Will this matter? The jar file is huge in size (about 200M).

Finally, please forgive me for my pool English!

Comment: You probably have some versioning conflicts. Check what else in on the classpath and see if something else includes the javax library (in a different version from the version required by your Spark version)

Comment: I will check, thank you!